# Problema ao iterar um array em php

Tags: php, foreach, for, codeigniter-3, php-5

Tenho o seguinte codigo.

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$arr1 = array(3, 4, 5);


$data = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

    $data["ca"] = $array[$i];

    for($k = 0; $k < count($arr1); $k++){

        $data["ser"] = $arr1[$k];
    }

}

print_r($data);
```

a ideia é que ele percorra todo o array, coisa que ele não está fazendo e ao percorrer ele imprima da seguinte forma:

```
Array ( [ca] => 1 [ser] => 3 )
Array ( [ca] => 2 [ser] => 4 )
Array ( [ca] => 3 [ser] => 5 )
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar `['ca'][] = $array[$i]`; Porque nesse caso ele apenas está substituindo o valor

Comment: @adventistaam sim, só que ai ele duplica os valores do meu array.

Comment: É porque o segundo for está dentro do primeiro. Então toda vez ele vai repetir

Comment: @adventistaam sim, porém eu coloque em um loop dentro de outro loop justamente para poder intercalar os valores, porque se eu colocar um fora do outro ele me dá esse resultado Array ( [ca] => 1, [ca] => 2, [ser] => 1, [ser] => 2 ).

Comment: Mas os valores serão os que estão no array. A menos que você tire o segundo for

Comment: @adventistaam opa é verdade era só ter tirado o segundo `for` e colocado tudo dentro de um só `for`, vlw.

Comment: Espero que tenha funcionado

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Montar array bidimensional PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344460/montar-array-bidimensional-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido ao tirar o o segundo `for` e iterar em apenas um `loop`

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
$arr1 = array(3, 4, 5);


$data = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

    $data["ser"] = $arr1[$i];
    $data["ca"] = $array[$i];
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: Desta forma somente imprimirá a última inserção no array $data... Print_r deve ser colocado dentro do for.

Comment: @reculos-gerbi-neto vlw pelo toque

Comment: Veja nesta pergunta outra forma de se fazer isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344460/montar-array-bidimensional-php