# Montar array bidimensional PHP

Tags: php

Preciso montar um array bidimensional através de 2 arrays recebidos via post.

Exemplo dos arrays que recebo:

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => disc03
        [1] => disc04
    )


    Array
    (
        [0] => prof03
        [1] => prof04
    )
```

A partir dos dois, preciso montar a seguinte saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [disciplina] => disc03
            [professor] => prof03
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [disciplina] => disc04
            [professor] => prof04
        )

)
```

Basicamente preciso uni-los onde as chaves forem iguais, mas alterando o valor da chave para 'disciplina' e 'professor' respectivamente.
O objetivo é fazer múltiplos inserts no banco de dados usando um array.

(Uso Codeigniter 3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se for fazer isso no PHP, basta utilizar o [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php):

```
$disciplinas = ['x', 'y'];
$professores = ['1', '2'];

$resultado = array_map(function ($disciplina, $professor) {
    return compact('disciplina', 'professor');
}, $disciplinas, $professores);

print_r($resultado);
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [disciplina] => x
            [professor] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [disciplina] => y
            [professor] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson! Funcionou perfeitamente!