# Pegar valor do array

Tags: php

Estou precisando pegar os valores do array onde tem as fotos. Consegui pegar o que te o nome, mas as fotos estou batendo cabeça...rs

Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Teste 8
            [1] => Teste b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => avaria_20190614005447368417.jpg
            [1] => avaria_20190614005450305809.jpg
        )

)
```

php

```
<?php
  $avariasIni = unserialize($row_rsRegistros['avariasIni']);

  foreach($avariasIni[0] as $avaIni => $avaKey) {
    echo $avaKey ." = ". $avaIni ."<br />";
  }
?>
```

A variavel que estou pegando o nome é `$avaKey`, agora preciso pegar o nome da foto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está utilizando um array multidimensional. Caso os dois arrays possuam a mesma quantidade de itens, você pode utilizar o loop da seguinte forma.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($avariasIni[0]); $i++) {
    echo $avariasIni[0][$i] ." = ". $avariasIni[1][$i] ."<br />";
}

//Saída
//Teste 8 = avaria_20190614005447368417.jpg
//Teste b = avaria_20190614005450305809.jpg
```

Comment: Vitor, é possível fazer com o foreach?

Comment: Se der para faze com foreach para mim é melhor.

Comment: @Tiago, vou colocar um **Edit** para atualizar a resposta :)

Comment: @Tiago, cada valor de um array referencia o valor do outro array?

Answer (score 4):

Como já mostrei em [Montar array bidimensional PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344460/montar-array-bidimensional-php), a função `array_map` já faz esta associação para você:

```
$dados= [
    ['Teste 8', 'Teste B'],
    ['avaria_20190614005447368417.jpg', 'avaria_20190614005450305809.jpg']
];

$agrupado = array_map(function ($nome, $imagem) {
    return compact('nome', 'imagem');
}, $dados[0], $dados[1]);

var_export($agrupado);
```

A saída seria:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'nome' => 'Teste 8',
    'imagem' => 'avaria_20190614005447368417.jpg',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'nome' => 'Teste B',
    'imagem' => 'avaria_20190614005450305809.jpg',
  ),
)
```

Basta iterar e fazer o que deseja:

```
foreach ($agrupado as $dado) {
  echo "{$dado['nome']} - {$dado['imagem']}", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Gerando a saída:

```
Teste 8 - avaria_20190614005447368417.jpg
Teste B - avaria_20190614005450305809.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom, parece que você está com um array multidimensional onde os índices de um fazem relação com o conteúdo do outro, logo, você pode começar organizando isso (o ideal seria já vir organizado onde você trata o envio/consulta desses valores).

Criei um array com a mesma estrutura que a sua para testes.

```
$avariasIni = array(
    array('Teste 8', 'Teste B'),
    array('avaria_20190614005447368417.jpg', 'avaria_20190614005450305809.jpg'));
```

Com isso fiz uma pequena rotina para retornar o array organizado onde você pode acessar e manipular como quiser.

```
foreach($avariasIni as $key => $avarias){
    if($key == 0){
        foreach($avarias as $key2 => $nome){
            $temp[$key2]['nome_foto'] = $nome;
        }
    }
    if($key == 1){
        foreach($avarias as $key2 => $foto){
            $temp[$key2]['link_foto'] = $foto;
        }
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome_foto"]=>
    string(7) "Teste 8"
    ["link_foto"]=>
    string(31) "avaria_20190614005447368417.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome_foto"]=>
    string(7) "Teste B"
    ["link_foto"]=>
    string(31) "avaria_20190614005450305809.jpg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você conhece o comprimento dos arrays e/ou deseja acessar apenas um item específico, você pode acessá-lo diretamante pelo seu índice.

```php
$avariasIni = unserialize($row_rsRegistros['avariasIni']);

// printa o nome e o arquivo do primeiro item

print $avariasIni[0][0]; // nome do primeiro arquivo
print $avariasIni[1][0]; // nome do arquivo do primeiro item

print $avariasIni[1][0]; // nome do segundo arquivo
print $avariasIni[1][1]; // nome do arquivo arquivo do segundo item

// restante do codigo aqui...
```